# Getting null pointer object on hilt inject object in activity when run test cases

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, dagger-hilt

Please check below my **Module** class in which I have defined my object which need to be inject using `Hilt`

> **NVModule.kt**

```
     @Module
     @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
     class NVModule {

     @Provides
     @Named("ProfileHelper")
     fun  abprovideProfileHelper(): ProfileHelper {
     return ProfileHelper(AppController.getInstance())
      }
     }
```

And now please check my Interface by which i have used the `EntryPoint` to access my dependency injection outside the `Activity/Fragment` like `Helper` class.

```
 @EntryPoint
       @InstallIn(SingletonComponent.class)
       public interface CommonHiltInterface {
       @Named("ProfileHelper")
       public ProfileHelper provideProfileHelper();
       }
      }
```

Now please check the my `Activity` class on which i have used the dependency injection like below and ***it is working fine here***. Means getting dependency injection properly

```
   public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity{
    private ActivityHomescreenBinding 
    activityHomescreenBinding;
    private Activity context;
    
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   context = this;

   activityHomescreenBinding = 
   DataBindingUtil.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), 
   R.layout.activity_homescreen, null, false);
   setContentView(activityHomescreenBinding.getRoot());

   
  CommonHiltInterface commonHiltInterface = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(context, CommonHiltInterface.class);

commonHiltInterface.provideProfileHelper().setData();
 
     }
    }
```

But in case of the Test cases , dependency injection getting NullPointerException . I am using the Robolectric for the test cases. Please check my below lines of code for the RobolectricTest case.

```
   @HiltAndroidTest
   @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
   @Config(application = HiltTestApplication.class,
   sdk =  Build.VERSION_CODES.N, manifest = Config.NONE)
   public class HomeActivityTest {

   @Rule
   public HiltAndroidRule hiltRule = new 
   HiltAndroidRule(this);

   @Before
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
   shadowOf(Looper.getMainLooper()).idle();
   hiltRule.inject();
   activity = 
   Robolectric.buildActivity(HomeActivity.class).
   create().resume().get();
    }
   }
```

**Note** :- 1). I have also use `@HiltAndroidApp()` for application class.and using 2.36 version for hilt dependency
2). My dependency injection working fine for the Java classes like Activity/Fagment and Helper classes , But not working in test cases.

Please check my dependency for Hilt are as follow

```
testImplementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.36'
kaptTest 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.36'
testAnnotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.36'
androidTestImplementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.36'
kaptAndroidTest 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.36'
```

**Application runs successfully but in case of Test case I am getting the null pointer exception below lines of code in Activity (HomeActivity).**

```
 CommonHiltInterface commonHiltInterface = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(context, CommonHiltInterface.class);

commonHiltInterface.provideProfileHelper().setData();
```

Comment: You might want to take some time to properly format and indent your code, it's quite hard to read as it stands.

Comment: 1. There is one class in kotlin  module class for inject object ProfileHelper class
2. one is interface for entry point for injected class object.
3. I am using profileHelper class method help of Appcontroller class in main activity, it get  succesfully when whole application run.
4. it is getting null pointer in mainactivity when run test cases on provideProfileHelper.setData.

Comment: @HenryTwist Now I have modified the code for the better understanding , please help him.Thanks